# How to remove liquibase changelog or fix an error?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, liquibase

I am using jhipster to create my application. While running `./mvnw clean verify` i get the following error message:

```
Table "TEST_CASE" already exists; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.test_case (id BIGINT NOT NULL, case_number INT NOT NULL, author VARCHAR(255), description CLOB, test_group_id BIGINT NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT PK_TEST_CASE PRIMARY KEY (id)) [42101-197]
```

If i try to start the application normaly it does kind of work but i get a similar message.

I tried to remove the liquibase changelog to fix it but in that case there are other errors. I have no data or migration so its not a problem to loose all of it.

I can imagin a few possible solutions but i dont know how to execut any of those:

- remove liquibase changelog/ migration files to start with a clean state
- Fix liquibase issue
- reset jhipster datamodel (similar to the first solution)

Comment: Which database?

Comment: H2 in developement and Postgres in production. But the problem does exist with H2 DB. I havent tried it with postgres.

Comment: Did you modify the test_case entity definition and then re-generated without removing previous migration? Have you followed doc about migrations ? see https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#database-updates

Comment: Yes that might be the problem. I did not do anything about migration so far. Do you mean that i should remove the privious migration file before i can change an entity again?

Comment: Yes either new migration should replace previous one (easy if you don't care about existing data), or you must write a migration that alters the table and liquibase diff can help as explained in doc.

Comment: I will try to replace the previous one. Thank you very much!